# Equivalent of Simple Data Loader in Modelbuilder

Tags: arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, arccatalog

I have a model which processes a user specified polygon feature class `InputFC`, with the final result a dissolved (based on a user specified dissolve field `D_FIELD`) polygon feature class `OutputFC`. The model also creates a file geodatabase and an empty feature class called `FinalFC` using `InputFC` as a template (for the attribute schema).

If I were doing this manually, I would now load the data from `OutputFC` into `FinalFC` using the `Simple Data Loader` in ArcCatalog. Since they have the same table structure, ArcCatalog would automatically match `D_FIELD` in `OutputFC` to its matching `D_FIELD` in `FinalFC` and load the data into it. The rest of the attributes in `FinalFC` would be empty. Is this functionality available as a tool for ModelBuilder, or is there a better way to get the dissolved data into the correct table structure?

Comment: What is the purpose of creating the blank FC template?  Couldn't you just use the blank file geodatabase as the output for your dissolved feature class?

Comment: The dissolved output will only have the one field; I need it to have the same schema as the original input, even if I don't necessarily populate all the attributes with data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [Append](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000050000000) tool is what you're looking for.  Just make sure the schema_type is set to 'TEST'.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I had to set the schema_type to `NO_TEST` though, as I needed it to match my dissolve field to the final feature class. It worked as expected, with only the dissolve field populated and the other fields empty. Thanks!